# Sharepoint 2013: unexpected response from server. The status code of response is ‘500’

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have term driven navigation when I try to add new term in "term store management", on the TERM-Driven-page link I am getting below mentioned error.

> Unexpected response from server. The status code of response is `500`.
>   The status text of response is
>   `system.servicemodel.serviceactivationexception`

Comment: Weirdly enough, I had the same problem yesterday though with another issue, but it was the same exception. Try to recycle your SharePoint web application in IIS, that made it work for me!

Comment: I tried recreating the Meta Data service with my old backup. even then no improvement. still i am getting this weird error.

Comment: Check this helpful article **[Error with the request to the server: Unexpected response from a server. The status code of the response is '500'. The status text of the response is 'System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException'.](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/the-server-was-unable-to-save-the-form-at-this-time-please-try-again-in-sharepoint-2013/)**